# How to remove extra icon in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I do not have any NA values in my data set, but ggplot plots as if I do (red dot at top of legend).  How can I remove these non-existent NA? I do not want NA in my legend.  There are no NA's in genera and that is where I'm having the issue.

I have tried na.omit and it didn't work (removed all NAs-meaning removed months that had no values, but I need to show all months).  Also tried case.complete.  Also tried [!is.na(genera_month$genera),] - I think this should be correct, but I keep getting an error.

```
    shell <- ggplot(genera_month) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Site, y = factor(word,levels=c("February", "January", "December", "November", "October","September", "August")), color = genera, size=rank), alpha=0.5) + 
scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
scale_y_discrete(name = "") +  
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", angle = 45,hjust = 1)) 
shell
shell+scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 8))
shell + scale_size(guide=FALSE)

         Site            date           word    genera              rank
    76  SJR Turner Cut  8/26/2020   8   August  Microcystis          2
    77  SJR Turner Cut  8/31/2020   8   August  Microcystis          2
    80  SJR Turner Cut  8/31/2020   8   August  Pseudananabaena      1
    86  SJR Turner Cut  12/10/2020  12  December                    NA
    88  SJR Turner Cut  2/10/2021   2   February                    NA
    87  SJR Turner Cut  1/5/2021    1   January                     NA
    85  SJR Turner Cut  11/9/2020   11  November                    NA
    83  SJR Turner Cut  10/12/2020  10  October                     NA
    84  SJR Turner Cut  10/20/2020  10  October                     NA
    78  SJR Turner Cut  9/8/2020    9   September   Microcystis     2
    79  SJR Turner Cut  9/22/2020   9   September   Microcystis     3
    81  SJR Turner Cut  9/8/2020    9   September   Pseudananabaena 1
    82  SJR Turner Cut  9/22/2020   9   September   Pseudananabaena 1
    26  SJR Big Break   12/10/2020  12  December                    NA
    28  SJR Big Break   2/8/2021    2   February                    NA
    27  SJR Big Break   1/7/2021    1   January                     NA
    25  SJR Big Break   11/16/2020  11  November                    NA
    22  SJR Big Break   10/1/2020   10  October     Microcystis         3
    23  SJR Big Break   10/19/2020  10  October     Microcystis         3
    24  SJR Big Break   10/27/2020  10  October                     NA
    20  SJR Big Break   9/4/2020    9   September                   NA
    21  SJR Big Break   9/11/2020   9   September   Microcystis     2


structure(list(Site = c("Sherman Lake", "Sherman Lake", "Sherman Lake", 
"Sherman Lake", "Sherman Lake", "Sherman Lake", "Sherman Lake", 
"Sherman Lake", "Sherman Lake", "Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", 
"Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", 
"Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", "Sac at Decker", 
"SJR Big Break", "SJR Big Break", "SJR Big Break", "SJR Big Break", 
"SJR Big Break", "SJR Big Break", "SJR Big Break", "SJR Big Break", 
"SJR Big Break", "Sac Isleton", "Sac Isleton", "Sac Isleton", 
"Sac Isleton", "Sac Isleton", "Sac Isleton", "Sac Isleton", "Sac Isleton", 
"Sac Isleton", "CS  Riyer Island", "CS  Riyer Island", "CS  Riyer Island", 
"CS  Riyer Island", "CS  Riyer Island", "CS  Riyer Island", "CS  Riyer Island", 
"CS  Riyer Island", "CS  Riyer Island", "CS S Lib Island", "CS S Lib Island", 
"CS S Lib Island", "CS S Lib Island", "CS S Lib Island", "CS S Lib Island", 
"CS S Lib Island", "CS S Lib Island", "CS S Lib Island", "Franks Tract", 
"Franks Tract", "Franks Tract", "Franks Tract", "Franks Tract", 
"Franks Tract", "Franks Tract", "Franks Tract", "Franks Tract", 
"Franks Tract", "OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", 
"OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", 
"OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", "OR Holland Tract", "SJR Turner Cut", 
"SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", 
"SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", 
"SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", "SJR Turner Cut", 
"MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", 
"MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", 
"MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island", "MR Bacon Island"), date = c("9/8/2020", 
"9/11/2020", "10/1/2020", "10/19/2020", "10/27/2020", "11/10/2020", 
"12/9/2020", "12/9/2020", "1/7/2021", "9/8/2020", "9/11/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "10/19/2020", "10/27/2020", "11/10/2020", "12/11/2020", 
"1/7/2021", "2/8/2021", "2/10/2021", "9/4/2020", "9/11/2020", 
"10/1/2020", "10/19/2020", "10/27/2020", "11/16/2020", "12/10/2020", 
"1/7/2021", "2/8/2021", "9/9/2020", "9/30/2020", "10/13/2020", 
"10/21/2020", "11/13/2020", "11/20/2020", "12/11/2020", "1/8/2021", 
"2/10/2021", "9/1/2020", "9/9/2020", "9/30/2020", "10/16/2020", 
"10/21/2020", "11/13/2020", "12/11/2020", "1/8/2021", "2/10/2021", 
"9/1/2020", "9/9/2020", "9/30/2020", "10/16/2020", "10/21/2020", 
"11/13/2020", "12/11/2020", "1/8/2021", "2/10/2021", "9/2/2020", 
"9/10/2020", "9/29/2020", "10/13/2020", "10/22/2020", "10/22/2020", 
"11/13/2020", "12/9/2020", "1/7/2021", "2/8/2021", "8/31/2020", 
"9/8/2020", "9/8/2020", "9/29/2020", "10/12/2020", "10/20/2020", 
"11/9/2020", "12/10/2020", "1/5/2021", "2/10/2021", "8/26/2020", 
"8/31/2020", "9/8/2020", "9/22/2020", "8/31/2020", "9/8/2020", 
"9/22/2020", "10/12/2020", "10/20/2020", "11/9/2020", "12/10/2020", 
"1/5/2021", "2/10/2021", "8/31/2020", "9/8/2020", "8/31/2020", 
"9/8/2020", "9/29/2020", "10/12/2020", "10/20/2020", "11/9/2020", 
"12/10/2020", "1/5/2021", "2/10/2021"), Month = c(9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L), word = c("September", 
"September", "October", "October", "October", "November", "December", 
"December", "January", "September", "September", "October", "October", 
"October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "February", 
"September", "September", "October", "October", "October", "November", 
"December", "January", "February", "September", "September", 
"October", "October", "November", "November", "December", "January", 
"February", "September", "September", "September", "October", 
"October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "September", 
"September", "September", "October", "October", "November", "December", 
"January", "February", "September", "September", "September", 
"October", "October", "October", "November", "December", "January", 
"February", "August", "September", "September", "September", 
"October", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", 
"August", "August", "September", "September", "August", "September", 
"September", "October", "October", "November", "December", "January", 
"February", "August", "September", "August", "September", "September", 
"October", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February"
), genera = c("", "Microcystis", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "", "Lyngbya", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Dolichospermum", "", 
"", "", "", "Lyngbya", "Lyngbya", "Geitlerinema", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "Oscillatoria", "Lyngbya", "Lyngbya", "", "", "", 
"", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "", "Oscillatoria", 
"Microcystis", "", "", "", "", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", 
"Pseudananabaena", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "", "", "", 
"", "", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", 
"Pseudananabaena", "Pseudananabaena", "Pseudananabaena", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "Microcystis", "Microcystis", "Pseudananabaena", 
"Pseudananabaena", "Aphanizomenon", "Microcystis", "", "", "", 
"", ""), Rank = c("", "low", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"very low", "mod low", "", "low", "", "", "", "", "", "", "mod low", 
"low", "low", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "very low", 
"", "", "", "", "low", "low", "very low", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "low", "low", "low", "", "", "", "", "low", "low", "very low", 
"", "low", "low", "", "", "", "", "low", "low", "very low", "low", 
"low", "", "", "", "", "", "mod low", "mod low", "mod low", "low", 
"very low", "very low", "low", "", "", "", "", "", "", "mod low", 
"mod low", "very low", "very low", "very low", "low ", "", "", 
"", "", ""), mc = c(46.2, 117.72, 19.75, 27.23, 9.02, 11.17, 
27.66, 20.76, 10.55, 5.43, 32.64, 8.57, 27.32, 10.03, 68.25, 
17.86, 8.07, 15.07, 11.84, 220.79, 56.7, 12.95, 52.25, 11.11, 
31.16, 17.22, 7.31, 16.25, 7.37, 6.62, 8.31, 7.79, 12.09, 9.77, 
12.76, 8.37, 16.57, 7.18, 5.93, 3.63, 8.19, 0, 9.36, 11.38, 5.79, 
12.48, 7.83, 6.57, 0, 13.76, 0, 10.45, 7.44, 7.1, 11.27, 1105.03, 
390.71, 8.14, 86.64, 8.16, 8.16, 161.6, 20.04, 7.76, 10.83, 52.21, 
41.93, 41.93, 1e-04, 68.53, 20.25, 56.9, 20.37, 7.85, 10.19, 
142.88, 277.85, 90.58, 97.09, 277.85, 90.58, 97.09, 86.15, 14.9, 
24.16, 20.07, 8.72, 14.05, 40.99, 14.53, 40.99, 14.53, 9.42, 
71.64, 24.25, 59.91, 15.78, 7.94, 9.44), mcw = c(0.186, 0.221, 
0.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.127, 0, 0.135, 0, 0.144, 2.054, 0.118, 
0, 0, 0, 0.293, 0.531, 0.434, 0.15, 0.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.171, 0.137, 0.102, 0.159, 0, 0.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.137, 0.155, 0, 0.104, 0, 0, 0.938, 2.017, 
0.499, 0.509, 0.192, 0.192, 0, 0.127, 0, 0, 0.703, 1.002, 1.002, 
0.451, 0.449, 0.211, 0.194, 0.099, 0, 0, 3.843, 1.928, 4.592, 
0.807, 1.928, 4.592, 0.807, 0.121, 0.648, 0, 0.108, 0, 0, 4.427, 
2.608, 4.427, 2.608, 1.065, 0.274, 0.41, 0.169, 0.125, 0, 0), 
    rank = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 
    NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-99L))
```

[image]

Comment: OP, can you please provide your dataset in a format that can more easily be worked with?  Preference is given to the copying and pasting the output of `dput(genera_month)` from your console into the question, formatted as code.

Comment: I added the dput

Answer (score 0):

OP, you have a lot of missing data in the `genera` column of your dataset, which is mapped to color.  Since these rows have values for the `x` and `y` aesthetic, `ggplot2` is still drawing the points, even if the point will have a size = NA (meaning, it's invisible). After the points are drawn, the legend is created based on what was drawn, and in this case, you have invisible points that are then mapped to their value for `genera`, which is `""`.  There are a few ways to fix this, but the simplest is to just filter your data before plotting to eliminate those which contain this value:

```
shell <- ggplot(genera_month %>% dplyr::filter(genera!='')) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Site, y = factor(word,levels=c("February", "January", "December", "November", "October","September", "August")), color = genera, size=rank), alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "") +
  scale_color_discrete(drop=TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", angle = 45,hjust = 1)) 
shell
shell+scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 8))
shell + scale_size(guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

### EDIT

As OP wishes to keep the "empty" months shown in the y axis, you can still do that by setting the `limits` of the y axis scale:

```
shell <- ggplot(genera_month %>% dplyr::filter(genera!='')) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Site, y = factor(word,levels=c("February", "January", "December", "November", "October","September", "August")), color = genera, size=rank), alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "", limits=c("February", "January", "December", "November", "October","September", "August")) +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", angle = 45,hjust = 1)) 
shell
shell+scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 8))
shell + scale_size(guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I did get to this point, but I want it to still show November, January and February. I want to show that there is no detection during those months. However, I do not want the empty red dot at the top of my legend.

Comment: You can do that by supplying `limits` which list out all the desired levels to the `scale_y_discrete()` function.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help-really appreciate it.